# ExpressJS - render page with arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using ExpressJS. In the router (index.js) I create an Object of the InxedController and pass a String in for the constructor. Then i call the showDefaultFeed method.

"index.hbs" (view) should print my argument from the constructor.

Instead I get the error message:

```
res.render('index.hbs', { this.title });
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

This is my code:

```
//indexController.js file

function IndexController(titleArg) {
this.title = titleArg;
}

IndexController.prototype.showDefaultFeed = function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.hbs', { this.title });
}

module.exports = IndexController;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you're passing to `index.hbs` is not a valid object.

`res.render('index.hbs', { this.title });`

Do this instead

`res.render('index.hbs', { title: this.title });`

Comment: Thank you, didnt know it was that easy.